# На сколько это правильно? (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom

Только начал учить Js, сейчас прохожу блок по DOM.
Написал абстрактную регистрацию пользователя с проверкой на совпадение паролей, на сколько правильно я это сделал?

```js
var regbutton = document.querySelectorAll('.button')
var form = document.querySelector('form')
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
var h3 = document.querySelector('h3')
var reginfo = document.querySelectorAll('p')

regbutton[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(form.style.display === 'none'){
        form.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        form.style.display = 'none'
    }

    regbutton[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(inputs[1].value == inputs[2].value){
            h3.textContent = 'Вы завершили регистрацию!'
            reginfo[1].textContent = inputs[0].value
            reginfo[2].textContent = inputs[1].value
        } else {
            h3.textContent = 'Пароли не совпадают!'
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <h2>Форма регистрации</h2>
    <p>Пройдите регистрацию.</p>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#" class="a-reg">Регистрация</a>
    </div>

    <form action="#">
        <label for="">Имя:</label><br>
        <input type="text"><br>
        <label for="" class="password">Пароль:</label><br>
        <input type="text"><br>
        <label for="" class="re-password">Повторите пароль:</label><br>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#" class="a-reg">Регистрация</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Не хватает 13 точек с запятой... Потому что вот:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var regbutton = document.querySelectorAll('.button'),
        form = document.querySelector('form'),
        inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
        h3 = document.querySelector('h3'),
        reginfo = document.querySelectorAll('p');

    form.style.display = 'none';    /** нужно чтобы форма была отключена при загрузке 
    сайта, лучше начальные стили задавать с помощью CSS */

    regbutton[0].addEventListener('click', function () {    
      form.style.display = 'block';    
      regbutton[0].style.display = 'none';
    });    // здесь вам if else не нужны, данной функцией имеет смысл воспользоваться 
    только раз


    regbutton[1].addEventListener('click', function () {
      if(inputs[1].value === inputs[2].value && inputs[0].value !== '' && 
         inputs[1].value !== '' && inputs[2].value !== '') {

    /** в условии вам лучше проверят на строгое равенство ===,
    так как при вводе пароля в формате "0" == 0 у вас выйдет true. И вам нужно 
    проверить не пустые ли у вас строки, тоже вернет true.
    Нужно проверить не пустое ли поле с именем пользователя */


        h3.textContent = 'Спасибо ' + inputs[0].value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
        inputs[0].value.slice(1) + '. Вы успешно завершили регистрацию!';

        // здесь я немного изменил ваш код, думаю так будет красивее.


      } else {
        if (inputs[0].value === '' && inputs[1].value !== '' && inputs[2].value !== '') 
        { 
          h3.textContent = 'Введите имя пользователя!';

        } else if (inputs[0].value !== '' && inputs[1].value === '' && 
          inputs[2].value === '') {

           h3.textContent = 'Введите пароль!';

        } else {

          h3.textContent = 'Пароли не совпадают!';
        }  
        // здесь добавил несколько простых условий проверки при заполнении полей формы
      }
    });

    // после каждой инструкции нужно ставить ( ; )
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное)